# Sharing a file without them being able to edit the main file

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2016

I need to either create or share my project with others.  I don't want them to be able to make changes to my project though.  I've tried creating a new one, but they still are able to make changes to my file.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Been a while since I've used 2016, from memory:

File -> Save As -> Tools -> General Options

In there, there should be an option to save a version as 'Read Only.'

Screenshot as requested, although this is 2013, I believe the option is the same:

[image: Save options - read only]

Comment: If you could provide a screenshot or a link to some canonical product documentation, then I would definitely upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

I would try and consider a wider organisational policy and set up user access accordingly.

E.g. consider the persons that should be able to edit projects (e.g. project manager, all project support, PMO) and the persons that should be able to view projects (e.g. all PM's, relevant stakeholders, all programme managers). Set up groups and assign these groups to the projects.

Broadly, I would recommend that this is done at the DMS level / directory permissions rather than file by file. Document passwords are also a real pain to manage. I only use those for confidential docs .

Answer (score 0):

Technically, I don't think there is a way to enforce the requirement as stated.  You can make it more difficult for them to change the file, but ultimately, if they are motivated, they can create a file that includes their changes.  It may be that merely making it difficult is sufficient for your needs.

Depending on reasons for the requirement, you may wish to consider either
* Establishing an authoritative source for the data - that way it doesn't matter if they change the file, so long as everyone knows how to get the authoritative copy and the authoritative copy is easier to get than the edited copy.

- Sign the file.  Use any of a number of signature utilities to cryptographically sign the file.  Anyone can edit, but it is easy to identify the correct copy of the file.